# How to get uptime of Java application and not JVM

Tags: java, jvm

`ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime()` only returns the uptime of the JVM a Java application is running in. This is not the uptime of the Java application though. The Java application could be one of several running in the same JVM process or it could be started X amount of time after the JVM is started.

Is there a provided function for getting the Java application's uptime?

Comment: In which case are applications started at a time other than JVM startup? The only case I can think of is J2EE containers and those have become *pretty rare* these days. Could you specifiy the **specific** case you're after, because it's likely that you'll need a specific solution. There's no general concept of "applications" inside a single JVM.

Comment: Your question could be improved if you explain technically how you are launching multiple apps within the same JVM process.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no such feature built into Java.

You can easily write your own such feature to track elapsed time.

Capture the current moment as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.

```
Instant then = Instant.now() ;
```

When checking for elapsed time, capture the current moment again.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

Calculate elapsed time.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( then , now ) ;
```

Generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format.

```
String output = d.toString() ;
```

You can make that available via [JMX](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions) by writing your own `MBean`.

Answer (score 0):

"Java application" term is very vague here.
You obviously think it's not the same as the OS/JVM process so you must be using some kind of a container.

So the technique will be specific to the container you are running.
You might need to parse the logs to determine when the last deployment was done.
As mentioned by Basil Bourque, it's probably best to add your own tracking, perhaps by pushing an event to your metrics system after the app is started.